# zlib freezing the node event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib, event-loop

I can across a problem where my promisified `zlib.gunzip` would start eating up all the CPU and causing my instances to become unresponsive (I checked the Event Loop Lag and it would sometimes be insanely high). From what I read, `zlib` is using the worker threads so I never thought that was the problem. The code looks like:

```
const util = require('util');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const gunzip = util.promisify(zlib.gunzip);

const fetchData = async (url) => {
  const response = await request({
    url,
    encoding: null,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  });

  // External service is sometimes returning 200 with HTML when rate limiting
  if (response.headers['content-type'] === 'text/html; charset=UTF-8') {
    response.statusCode = 500;
    throw new ServiceError('External service error');
  }

  return gunzip(response.body);
};
```

The external provider allows for gzipped and text (UTF-8) responses. As soon as I switched to the text version, the CPU usage went from 100% to 10% in production (with maybe 3-4 QPS). Thing is, most of the time I have to throw my `ServiceError` because I am being rate limited and the zlib code path is not executed in that case, but the CPU was still choking.

Any idea why that is the case? Am I forgetting something that might cause calls to be sync or block the event loop?

EDIT 1: I realized the problem only occurs when something throws in the method. Otherwise it is working as expected.